# How to compare a value from change event

Tags: javascript, angular

I made a list of select options and want to get the value on change event and compare it to a string. It looks simple but I am not getting any result nor an error.

this is my ts file :

```js
changed(e) {
  if(e === "0001") console.log('hey')
}
```

and this is the HTML template :

```html
<select (ngModelChange)="changedTier($event)" [(ngModel)]="selTier">
  <option *ngFor="let t of tiers" value="{{t.CT_Num}} "> {{t?.CT_Intitule}}</option>
</select>
```

this is on object of Tiers array :

```
{CT_Num: "0001", cbCT_Num: {…}, CT_Intitule: "TEST", CT_Type: 1}
```

What am I doing wrong ??

Comment: function name 'changed' or 'changedTier' ?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hcchqa -see this its working

Comment: @Shubh how is it working ?? it is not

Comment: @bg1 see the console its printing the value on change

Comment: i know that the probleme is that it's not printing hey when it's equal to "0001"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having a space after the the interpolation:

```html
value="{{t.CT_Num}} "
```

This matters (when using `value` and not `[value]`), so when comparing the two values they won't match. A space is considered "value". So it's as simple as removing the space:

```html
value="{{t.CT_Num}}"
```

See demo: **[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-keret5?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

I like to use variable binding `[]` though in these cases, that would also avoid the issue, even if you mistakenly would have a space:

```html
[value]="t.CT_Num"
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, use change event and pass the event target value:

```
<select (change)="changed($event.target.value)" [(ngModel)]="selTier">
    <option *ngFor="let t of tiers" value="{{t.CT_Num}} "> {{t?.CT_Intitule}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: i am using ngChangeModel because i want the function to be fired even the select is still focused besides i am getting the value .

Answer (score 0):

```
changed(e) {
 if(e === "0001") { 
  console.log('hey');
  }
}
```

The syntax was wrong in your function. Make sure your function call has the same name in the html. Also make sure that your iterable items are of the same type.

Comment: the function name is right i just typed it wrong here that's it the probleme is i am not getting hey in the console

Comment: How does your array / object look? Could you add the code?